# Python to return from for loop

Tags: python, if-statement

Which would be the best practice in Python?

```
# style1
def check(value)
    for i in range(10):
        if i==value:
            break
    else:
        return False
    return True

#style2
def check(value)
    for i in range(10):
        if i==value:
            return True
    return False
```

I feel uneasy to use the 2nd style since it returns without breaking the loop.

Note: The code snippet is just an example.

Comment: IHMO this will be highly opinionated. Both versions of ``check()`` are perfectly valid. Refer to [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Is there an error in the indentation of the first style?

Comment: @user2963623: No, Python supports `else` clauses on loops. If the loop doesn't `break`, the `else` runs.

Comment: The only reason I'd say style2 is because not all languages have for-else, so you're more likely to get 10 seconds of head scratching.

Comment: Plus one for an interesting question before bed. Cheers.

Comment: A ``return`` terminate any loop construct just as ``break`` does (*but ``break`` will only terminate the innermost loop*).

Comment: In my experience, style 1 is unfamiliar to a lot of python developers. Remember not everyone thinks they need to read the manual. Style 2 is also the more readable of the two in my opinion.

Comment: I have clarified my answer as well as I can. I have also attempted to clarify your question to better conform to the rules of the site without changing any of your meaning. Let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. My opinion is that style 2 is more readable, but the code in U2EF1's answer is even more readable and Pythonic, and almost certainly faster as well (because the looping would be done in C).

Answer (score 3):

This is rather convoluted, you're using the break as a goto statement.

```
def check(value)
    for i in range(10):
        if i==value:
            break
    else:
        return -1
    return 1
```

Just do the direct thing, which is simpler and easier to read, uses less control flow and lines of code, and therefore much more maintainable:

```
def check(value)
    for i in range(10):
        if i==value:
            return 1
    return -1
```

I noted your concern about returning before exiting from the loop, it is not problematic at all in Python, and in fact should be encouraged so long as each exit point in your function is clear.

#### Further recommendations:

Better than this, it would be more Pythonic to return True or False.

In Python3, for this code, you can simply do this, since range supports membership testing:

```
def check(value)
    return value in range(10) # in Python 2, use xrange
```

---

#### Explanation to commentators:

To explain to the confused commentators, in Python 2, you wouldn't want to use range because it materializes the entire list in memory before testing for membership.

You can see this by disassembling the code:

```
>>> dis.dis('4 in range(10)')
          0 DELETE_SLICE+2 
          1 SLICE+2        
          2 BUILD_MAP        8302
          5 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 28257
          8 BUILD_LIST      10341
         11 <49>           
         12 <48>           
         13 STORE_SLICE+1
```

and it takes measurably more time:

```
>>> timeit.repeat('4 in xrange(10)')
[0.2592649459838867, 0.25824499130249023, 0.2570168972015381]
>>> timeit.repeat('4 in range(10)')
[0.30319905281066895, 0.2991337776184082, 0.31210994720458984]
```

this extra time grows quite a lot with the size of the list:

```
>>> timeit.repeat('4 in xrange(100)')
[0.2945590019226074, 0.25594496726989746, 0.2511298656463623]
>>> timeit.repeat('4 in range(100)')
[0.7569739818572998, 0.7626628875732422, 0.7740590572357178]
```

Comment: `in` operates on iterables, not just lists, so Python 2 also supports `x in range(y)`.

Comment: In Python 2, you're not testing it on a range object, you're materializing an entire list, and then testing if the number is in the list, it's far less efficient.

Comment: `xrange` doesn't support `__contains__`. Membership testing iterates through the xrange. Also, note that Python 3's `range` only does `in` efficiently for ints and bools. If for some reason you try to use it with another type, e.g. a NumPy int32, it has to iterate through the range.

Comment: I think at this point we're really going beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @AaronHall Not true at all. While `in` does operate in O(n) time, if given a generator, [it will only instantiate as many as needed](http://codepad.org/uCdlPSms).

Comment: In Python 2, range returns a list.  This is very easy to demonstrate: `type(range(10))` => `<type 'list'>` and the help is quite explicit in that it returns a list. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm sure you'll find my answer now fully addresses your points.

Answer (score 2):

Style 2, although I'd also question why you're returning `1` and `-1` instead of `True` and `False`, and why you're iterating over a range in the first place. So really, style 3 or 4:

```
def check3(value):
    return value in range(10)

def check4(value):
    return 0 <= value < 10
```

Comment: And for slightly more complex cases `any`/`all` can be used... The code snippet _needs_ to be more complex before this question is really meaningful

Comment: This doesn't really address the concerns of the asker.

Comment: @AaronHall It's kind of a weird question, but the answer really is just "Style 2 is fine".